# FormData sends empty data using axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, multipartform-data, form-data

I want send my data from vue to api. I don't know why my formData is empty. You can see snapshot attached. I've tried several hours using several links on stackoverflow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555705/axios-formdata-getting-empty-object) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587831/how-to-append-files-and-data-to-formdata-in-vue-js).

[image]

my confirm method:

```
async confirm () {
      let formData = new FormData()
      let params = {
        name: this.product.name,
        department_id: this.departmentId,
        category_id: this.categoryId,
        sub_category_id: this.subCategoryId,
        brand_id: this.brandId,
        weight: parseInt(this.product.weight),
        unit_weight: this.product.unitWeight === 'gram' ? 'g' : 'ml',
        volume: {
          length: parseInt(this.product.volume.length),
          width: parseInt(this.product.volume.width),
          height: parseInt(this.product.volume.height)
        }
      }
      formData.append('file', this.imageFile)
      formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(params))
      console.log(formData.getAll('data'))
      console.log(formData.getAll('file'))
      console.log('this.imagefile', this.imageFile)
      console.log('this.params', params)
      console.log('formData', formData)
      this.fullscreenLoading = true
      await this.klikdailyAPI().post('products', formData).then(result => {
        let message = this.product.name + ' succesfully created'
        this.$store.commit('products/setMessage', message)
        this.$router.push('/products')
        this.fullscreenLoading = false
      }).catch(err => {
        this.snackbar = true
        this.snackbarObject = {
          color: 'error',
          text: 'ERROR! ' + err.response.data.message
        }
      })
    }
```

my api method:

```
klikdailyAPI () {
      return axios.create({
        baseURL: `${url}/api/v1/`,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('tokenApi')}`,
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
    }
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Formdata It did not display in the console it converted as a binary. When you post data displayed in your API call.form data,

Comment: Ok, so how to send data from vue to api using axios? I use this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587831/how-to-append-files-and-data-to-formdata-in-vue-js

Comment: `axios.post('/api', data, header).then(
      response => {
          console.log(response);
      }
    )`  try this way. I hope it worked.

Comment: error undefined, because form data still empty

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'file': this.imagefile , 'data': params}

axios.post('/api', data, header).then( response => { console.log(response); } )
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25721480)