# JavaScript - Axios POST request empty form data (request payload)

Tags: javascript, file, post, axios, form-data

I have a Vue.js app which uses axios to interact with a Laravel API. I'm trying to make a POST request with an image file in it to upload in the backend.
The issue I'm having is that axios makes the POST request with empty payload.
I've tried sending it both as a plain JS object and with FormData. In both cases the request payload is empty. I've looked on the internet for hours but I was unable to find anything while trying to tackle the issue in the past few days...

This is how I make the request:

```
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', this.file);
console.log(...fd) //shows the file is there with its data
axios
    .post("/api/images", fd)
    .then(response => {
     //Handle success
    })
    .catch(errors => {
    //Catch errors
    });
```

This is how I get the file from the form:

```
let selectedImage = this.$refs.fileInput.files[0];
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
     this.file = event.target.result;
});
reader.readAsDataURL(selectedImage);
```

I've tried experimenting with the request headers and at the moment they are as follows:

```
"Accept" : "application/json",
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" + Math.random().toString().substr(2),
"Authorization": "Bearer " + this.user.api_token,
"X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
```

The responses from Laravel are always that the file is required (as expected when it's indeed missing).
I did try encoding the file in Base64 but I have trouble validating that it's an image in the backend.

I found this similar question but it wasn't of any help: [FormData sends empty data using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60860756/formdata-sends-empty-data-using-axios)

I want to send a file + JSON data but I'm ok with just making the file upload work. So... **How do I send a file from Vue.js app to Laravel API using Axios? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Did you find a solution? :C